# Protractor find element inside a repeater inside a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Given the following Html:

```
<custom-directive>
   <ng-container ng-repeat="item in items">
   {{item.description}}
   </ng-container>
</custom-directive>
```

How can I get the item where item.description equals "second item" inside the "custom-directive". 
I don't want to rely on an index, just the description itself.

Comment: Your given code are source code, not the HTML code on browser. Please open your page in browser and show HTML code of  the directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `by.binding` to get the child element.

```
var filteredItem = element.all(by.repeater("item in items")).filter(function(item){
  return item.element(by.binding("item.description")).getText().then(function(itemDescription){
    return itemDescription == "second item";
  });
}).first();
```

Comment: If I have another directive called "another-custom-directive", with the same ng-repeat, how can I make sure to retrieve the first one only?

Comment: @ShakSmith this should work. If you have multiple same ng-repeats -- first select parent, than child as usual. Though by.cssContainingText might be better.